# What is wrong with the way I'm overriding this method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to build a ray tracer. I have a class called Shape which I'm extending to the class of Sphere (and other shapes as well, like triangles). Shape has the method

```
virtual bool intersect(Ray) =0;
```

And so I create the Sphere class by

```
class Sphere : public Shape{
public:
    Sphere(){};
    bool intersect(Ray){/*code*/};
};
```

I have a main class which I use to create a list of Shape pointers. I create a Sphere pointer and do the following:

```
Sphere* sph = &Sphere();
shapes.emplace_front(sph); //shapes is a list of Shape pointers
```

Then when I want to trace the ray in another class I do the following:

```
for (std::list<Shape*>::iterator iter=shapes.begin(); iter != shapes.end(); ++iter) {
    Shape* s = *iter;
    bool hit = (*s).intersect(ray);
}
```

But I get the error that I cannot call intersect on a the virtual class Shape, even though it should be that *s points to a Sphere type object. What am I doing wrong with inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
Sphere *sph = &Sphere();
```

It creates a temporary object of type `Sphere`, stores a pointer to that temporary, then destroys the temporary. The result is nonsense.

Change it to this:

```
Sphere *sph = new Sphere();
```

things will work much better.